# Birt runtime Viewer Version : 4.9.0 - Engine Version: 4.9.0 - JRE version: 11.0.19

Tags: reportbug

I am trying to set up birt runtime on rocky Linux 8.8 and new on this platform.

welcome page is showing properly but when I tried to get its test report it display error.

HTTP Status 404 – Not Found
Type Status Report

Message The requested resource [/birt-4.9/frameset] is not available

Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

Apache Tomcat/10.0.21

I would really appreciate an immediate response I have been trying to solve this issue for a week but unable to resolve that issue.

Thanks.

---

I am trying to set up birt runtime on Rocky Linux 8.8 and Java version is 11.

The welcome page is displaying correctly but when I click on the view example button it displays an error that the frameset is not available.

[image: Welcome page of BIRT]

as I click on the view Example link it displays an error on the screen.

[image: Frameset Error]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

Comment: i have mentioned details in the answer section for your further understanding